# Get what is inside a beacon with regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to understand reGex, but for the moment is really hard...

I have a some linse this :

```
#<start>
blablablablal
blablablablal
blablablablal
blablablablal
blablablablal
#</start>
```

I already done something that get what is inside th beacons, but i can't find a way to get the beacon name.

I want to do a regex that give me only what is inside the #<**start**> and #< /**start**>  (just the start)

EDIT : sry i explained very badly.

What i'm trying to make, is something that give me the name of the open beacon and the closeing beacon.

basicaly, if i have

```
#<start>
blablablablal
blablablablal
blablablablal
blablablablal
blablablablal
#</start>
#<init>
blablablablal
blablablablal
blablablablal
blablablablal
blablablablal
#</init>
```

i want something that gave me start start init init.

How can i do this?

thx you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below regex.

```
#<\/?\K[^<>]+(?=>)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qU7nN0/6)

**OR**

Use this regex and get the string you want from group index 1.

```
#<\/?([^<>]+)>
```

- `#` Matches a literal `#` symbol.
- `\/?` Matches an optional `/` symbol.
- `()` called capturing groups which are used to capture characters.
- `[^<>]+` Negated character class which matches any character but not of `<` or `>` one or more times.
- `>` matches a literal `>` symbol.

Comment: sry man i explained badly.

i already have something that game me what is insite the beacon,
what i'm trying to make, is something that gave me the name of the beacon.

Comment: What do you mean by `beacon` ? What's your expected output?

Comment: yes sorry for the english ^^

so what i expect is this :

#<init> lololololol #</init>

if want to get booth of the "init" the name the beacons 

a beacon for me is <this>   how do you call it?

Comment: thx man  if is not to much, can you explain it a bit? ^^

else thx i will find some explanation on some websites :)à Thx! anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it captures the "beacon" of each group only once:

```
<(?P<beacon>[^>]).+(?P=beacon)
```